# Which code is cleaner, faster, or more elegant/preferable? Is there a function that does this already?

Tags: c#, xna

I wrote both of these for correcting rectangles. For example, if a rectangle has these properties:

X:32, Y:32, Width:-32, Height:-32

This will make the rectangle X:0, Y:0, Width:32, Height:32

```
if (r.Width < 0)
{
    r.X -= Math.Abs(r.Width);
    r.Width = Math.Abs(r.Width);
}
if (r.Height < 0)
{
    r.Y -= Math.Abs(r.Height);
    r.Height = Math.Abs(r.Height);
}
```

Here is #2

```
r.X -= Math.Abs(Math.Min(0, r.Width));
r.Width = Math.Abs(r.Width);

r.Y -= Math.Abs(Math.Min(0, r.Height));
r.Height = Math.Abs(r.Height);
```

They both work just fine. My question is which? I feel like the first may be faster and more readable but the second has less lines of code. Also, I feel like this is something that may have been invented already. Is there a method that does this already in the .NET or XNA Framework?

Thanks!!

Edit: Someone posted a shortened version of the second way which I really like and combined it into this:

```
r = new Rectangle(r.X + Math.Min(0, r.Width), r.Y + Math.Min(0, r.Height), Math.Abs(r.Width), Math.Abs(r.Height));
```

Honestly I prefer less lines to more and I don't think this is too complex. If anything I can place a comment or encapsulate it in to a method with a descriptive name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know r.Width and r.Height are < 0 why do you need to Abs on them?  Remove that and it will be even faster, and simpler.

```
if (r.Width < 0)
{
    r.X += r.Width;
    r.Width = -r.Width;
}
if (r.Height < 0)
{
    r.Y += r.Height;
    r.Height = -r.Height;
}
```

IMHO the second way you've written of doing this is just plain ugly.  You don't look at it and immediately realise what it's doing.  Remember KISS.

EDIT: I understand you like your code in the fewest lines possible so I re-engineered the above:

```
if (r.Width < 0) { r.X += r.Width; r.Width = -r.Width; } if (r.Height < 0) { r.Y += Height; r.Height = -r.Height; }
```

Just as simple - and all in one line of code!  It's even less characters on the line than your alternative....

Line count is generally not a good measure of programming beauty - but of course it's your code so you've got to go with what brings you the most joy.

Comment: I agree with you to an extent. Yes I think the above example is more clear and readable but this is an independent project that will never be seen by anyone else. Either way I understand the code and if I have it on one line I don't really have to look at it or think about it. It's kind of like encapsulating something to a class. You get it out of sight and can forget about it and think about other things. Of course this behavior can be mimicked by just placing the above code in to a method and giving it a descriptive name and I'm not necessarily against that either.

Comment: Yeah, on second thought I think I'm going with your code at the top of your post and placing it in to a method. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough - I get the drive the make code as short as possible too - but I fight it as other people will see my code (I would count future me who's forgotten how the code works as another person in this respect too).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is more readable, and it should also be slightly faster as it does less if there is nothing to do.

After checking if the values are negative, you know that they are negative, so you don't need any `Math.Abs`:

```
if (r.Width < 0) {
    r.Width = -r.Width;
    r.X -= r.Width;
}
if (r.Height < 0) {
    r.Height = -r.Height;
    r.Y -= r.Height;
}
```

Just for completeness, the second one can also be written will less `Math.Abs` calls as you know the sign of what comes out of `Math.Min` when it's not zero:

```
r.X += Math.Min(0, r.Width);
r.Width = Math.Abs(r.Width);
r.Y += Math.Min(0, r.Height);
r.Height = Math.Abs(r.Height);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've settled with this: r = new Rectangle(r.X + Math.Min(0, r.Width), r.Y + Math.Min(0, r.Height), Math.Abs(r.Width), Math.Abs(r.Height));